# Android Project Not Importing in ADT. Changed APK to zip, unpacked and can't make project from existing source

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt, eclipse-adt

I am thinking about working with another developer that gave me some links to APKs that I can look at before we start working. He told me I could rename them to zips and then extract them. That worked. Now I want to put the source in ADT as a project I can experiment with.

I run through all the dialogues for adding new Android Project from existing code, selecting the root directory and Eclipse lets me complete the wizard (nothings greyed out, looks like it should work, right?)

Well the project doesn't show up in Eclipse's Package Explorer.

Anybody had this problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ApkTool. That worked. It needed to decompile the classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no source files in the apk. Only compiled ones so there is no way of importing it into eclipse. You need to get the eclipse project from him.

I suggest You both read about versioning. ie git.

Comment: I just clarified the story by editing it, @JakubSzymion. I hadn't started working on the project officially at the time I wrote the question. I'm still not doing it yet, so I am not using git or any other source/version control (they use svn).

Comment: I wanted to point out that it is better to use git or other version control instead of sending/receiving an apk file because the sources from that file need to be decompiled and this is not in any way a good thing to do if there is a possibility to access the source in other way (git)